# Django upload file test returns 301

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-unittest, django-tests

I am trying to test an API post call which allow file uploading but I cannot get it to work, I am always receiving a 301

```
with open('video.mp4') as f:
    data = {'file': f}
    response = self.client.post('/api/upload_file', data, format='multipart')
```

The returned response is a 301

```
HttpResponsePermanentRedirect status_code=301, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/api/v1/assets/upload_file/"
```

I make sure the self.client is authenticated and the rest of the tests run correctly

```
self.client = APIClient()
self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the trailing slash in your test, so Django is automatically redirecting because you have [`APPEND_SLASH = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#append-slash).

To fix the problem, change your code to:

```
self.client.post('/api/upload_file/', data, format='multipart')
```